# How do I set an entry to PATH in .zshrc based on the user's CPU architecture?

Tags: macos, zshrc

My colleagues and I use the same **.zshrc** file. We would like it to automatically set an entry to **PATH** if the user has an M1 macbook which has a different way of installing a package (ansible in this case) compared to Intel based macs.

If user has an M1 macbook this should be added to PATH:

```
$HOME/Library/Python/3.8/bin
```

How do I go about doing that?

I was thinking about using `uname -p` to output processor architecture and then make a conditional within **.zshrc** but I'm not sure where to start. For instance I don't know if it's possible to add an entry to an already existing **PATH**.

Comment: Why not unconditionally add that directory if-and-only-if it exists? (If the way you're installing ansible on an Intel mac doesn't create that directory, an existence check is all you need).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good question/suggestion, I will try to alter your answer given below to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [[ $(arch) = arm64 ]]; then
  PATH+=:$HOME/Library/Python/3.8/bin
fi
```